Read and import excel files in Business Central
i need your help for a thing.
I've created a Power Automate flow where the system goes to Outlook, download the excel file from an e-mail and send that file in a SharePoint directory.
Now, i've to read those files in AL, in order to subsequently insert a record in the database.
I'll read the files with the Excel buffer but in first step, i don't know how to read the files from SharePoint.
Please, let me know if you've some ideas.
I've tried to use the API but i don't know how to use them properly and especially which is the SharePoint's link.

I'm going to use for the moment an Azure Relay.
Still not happy with this solution. So if you have an another way, try it.
